# Bootstrap Horizontal Drop Down menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have Horizontal drop-down menu like one in here [flipkart.com](http://www.flipkart.com) they have floating sidebar menu on hover.

This is my try [With Responsive Design]:-

JSFIDDLE Link - http://jsfiddle.net/QSFPK/

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span12">
<div class="span3">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
    <hr style="margin: -1px;">
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="menu">menu <span class="right-caret right"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="menu">menu <span class="right-caret right"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="menu">menu <span class="right-caret right"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="menu">menu <span class="right-caret right"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" title="menu">menu <span class="right-caret right"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu rightMenu">
            <li><a id="logout" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="span9">
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
        <h2>Hello World</h2>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

and here is my CSS :-

```
.rightMenu {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
.right-caret {

    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;    
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
```

JSFIDDLE Link - http://jsfiddle.net/QSFPK/
Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add some sort of class to the list items that have dropdowns, then you can use the css :hover selector to open up the menu with css such as:

```
li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display:block;
}
```

Here's an edited version of your code, but obviously you'll have to style it so there's no gap causing the mouse to go outside of the `<li>` item.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSFPK/2/

Comment: But i think, you have not checked, when you hover over the dropdown button `signout` the whole dropdown disappears.